# Leaving the US on H1B. Will I be cap-exempt in the future?

Tags: h1-visa

I am in the US and will be in H1B status starting October 1st. If I take a job in the UK with a different employer in January, do I forfeit my H1B status? If I want to move back to the US in two or three years, will I be cap exempt? That is, will a potential employer be able to provide me with an H1B without going through the lottery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I take a job in the UK with a different employer in January, do I forfeit my H1B status?

As far as US immigration law is concerned, you lose H-1B status every time you leave the US.  An H-1B worker can regain H-1B status on re-entry to the US only if the employer's petition (I-129) remains valid and the worker remains employed by the employer.  So yes, if you take a job in the UK with a different employer, you will lose your H-1B status.

> If I want to move back to the US in two or three years, will I be cap exempt?

H-1B cap exemption depends mostly on who employs you (see [8 USC 1184(g)(5)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1184#g_5)), so the answer to this question depends on who sponsors you when you return.

> That is, will a potential employer be able to provide me with an H1B without going through the lottery?

This depends on who the potential employer is.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this depends on the potential employer? Bullet point 7 in the link you provided seems to indicate that my petition in the future would not be counted towards the cap.

Comment: @arni that appears to be correct, unless your period of employment in the UK or your change of US employer resets your six-year limit. I don't know anything about the rules governing that.